# Can HTML5 input date change the day by default, not the year, on a arrow click?

Tags: html

The default HTML input date behavior on an arrow click, when no date part is selected, is to change the year in the date. Is it possible to modify/configure it so that the day, not the year, gets changed?

Code:

http://jsbin.com/toqenekaya/1/edit?html,output

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date

Comment: Clicking the arrow in chrome changes the day?

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard seems it must be locale specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this element work is first by choosing the date part you want to change then clicking the arrow.

Click on the day, month or year then the arrow key will change that chosen part value.

If you want it more customize, roll a plugin that allows the flexibility you need.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Yes, I know that. Our UX department thinks it is not user friendly as the user would only like to change the day, not the year, part of the date and currently one more click (to select the day part) is required from him.

Comment: You can do anything you like with a plugin with JS, not this HTML5 element though.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just wanted to confirm that it is not doable in pure HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

As I look on your code and click on an arrow without selecting a specific part, it already changes the day in Chrome.

---